# General solutions of $tan(2\theta)tan(\theta)=1$

Tags: trigonometry

This is basically a homework based question but I need a little bit clarification why, solutions to this equation based on different approaches do not satisfy the equation.

I solved this equation in the following way:

$tan(2\theta)tan(\theta)=1$
$=>\frac{sin(2\theta)sin(\theta)}{cos(2\theta)cos(\theta)}=1$
$=>0=\frac{cos(2\theta)cos(\theta)-sin(2\theta)sin(\theta)}{cos(2\theta)cos(\theta)}$
$=>cos(3\theta)=0$
$=>3\theta=(2n+1)\frac{\pi}2$
$\therefore \theta=(2n+1)\frac{\pi}6$,where $n\in \mathbb Z$

This solution turns out to be wrong since it also includes multiples of $\frac{\pi}2$ for which the equation is not satisfied. I cannot get where I did wrong.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde could you please tell me that does that mean these sort of equation basically have no specific way to exclude extraneous roots? Do we always need verification?

Comment: Sorry I didn't know that. I am extremely sorry and thanks a lot @FShrike

Comment: Turns out my answer was far more longwinded than the linked duplicate... good luck anyway